# Change the Telerik DateTimePicker element ID, but keep the name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

I have a ASP.NET MVC page with multiple forms on it, where each form edits a different instance of the same class. Each form also includes a Telerik DateTimePicker control. What I want is to have the element IDs change, but not the element name. So I have something like this:

```
string idString = string.Format("MyObject{0}", Model.ID)
@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m.SomeDate).HtmlAttributes(new { id = idString + "-SomeDate" })
```

Now this works mostly fine, except that at the bottom of the page, the auto-generated Javascript that Telerik puts in looks like:

```
jQuery('#SomeDate').tDateTimePicker({
  format:'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt', 
  minValue:new Date(1899,11,31,0,0,0,0), 
  maxValue:new Date(2100,0,1,0,0,0,0), 
  startTimeValue:new Date(2013,3,22,0,0,0,0), 
  endTimeValue:new Date(2013,3,22,0,0,0,0), 
  interval:30, 
  selectedValue:new Date(2013,3,22,11,9,1,180)
});
```

Note that my `idString` value didn't get put in. I can try:

```
@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m.SomeDate).Name(idString + "SomeDate")
```

And this makes the auto-generated Javascript correct (`jQuery('#MyObject123-SomeDate')`) but now the element name is wrong, so `TryUpdateModel` fails.

How can I get this to work? Thanks.

EDIT: I hacked this using the following Javascript, but this is a kludgy way to fix this.

```
$(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {
            var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];
            if (obj.id.indexOf("SomeDate") == -1)
                continue;
            obj.name = "SomeDate";
        }
    }, 150)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the Telerik object's `.InputHtmlAttributes` method.

```
@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m.SomeDate).InputHtmlAttributes(new { id = idString + "-SomeDate" })
```